# Configure tagged value in Enterprise Architect without configuring it in tagged value types

Tags: enterprise-architect

I want to get a tagged value named "ea_guid" under the "Tagged values" section of a particular Operation(Please refer to Image 1-this is our local environment). Here, under the Operation section, I want to add this tagged value. But I want to add it such that it doesn't exist in UML-Types->Tagged Values(Please refer to Image 2).

[image: Image 1]

[image: Image 2]

How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you add a tagged value using the *New tagged value* button (highlighted in the image below), you can **type** a new name for your tag instead of selecting an existing tagged value type.

[image]

Doing this doesn't automatically create a new tagged value type (tested in v15.2)

[image]